# Import Cascade classifier from Matlab to OpenCV 3.0

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, matlab-cvst, cascade-classifier

I have a cascade classifier made with Matlab 2014b, but the XML file says it is only compatible with OpenCV 2.4. I need to use it with OpenCV 3.0. Any way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is currently not possible to use the XML file with OpenCV 3.0.

Comment: I did try it and unfortunately it doesn't work, that's why I'm asking the question.
The error it gives is "Segmentation Fault".

Comment: Unfortunately, that means you cannot do it.  Unless you feel like comparing OpenCV 2.4 and 3.0 to see how exactly the XML format has changed.

Comment: @Zynk, On second thought, you may also want to send a bug report to OpenCV. Even if the format of the XML file has been changed, it should fail with something more graceful than a segmentation fault.

Comment: Yes, I tried to compare both but it was too hard to change it manually.
Thank you, I will do that.